# Overriding without calling parent method, violating Liskov Principle

Tags: java, oop, solid-principles, overriding

I am developing a simple project. And I have a conflict with meaning of Liskov Principle in my project.

I simplified my question of my project with this example:

```
public class Animal {  

     public void feed() {     

         // do something here         
     }    
}    


public class Dog extends Animal {

    // some methods and attributes

    @Override
    public void feed() {   

        // never call parent feed() method (super.feed())
    }
}
```

So, my question is, if I don't call parent method and write a completely new codes in override method, Is this violates Liskov Principle?

thanks.

Comment: No, as long as the content of the method still relates to *feeding an animal*...

Comment: how about using an empty method. Means that override parent class and let it empty? Is it violates liskov?

Comment: I'd say no, it's just stupid. You should rethink your class design if you face such a case where you need to override a base class method having behavior already  to do nothing...

Comment: Thanks a lot, can we say it is only bad implementation? (use empty override method) or it violates any other principles?

Comment: @AxarElses it's all about what do you try to model, when you don't need to implement feed method in certain implementation of Animal it's sounds like you need to introduce DomesticAnimal (Animal <- DomesticAnimal <- Dog) that depends on human and should be feed unlike of tiger or bear in example that cares by yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it will not violate the Liskov Principle as long as the subclass' implementation satisfies the expectations of the base class.

Comment: @Dylin, thanks, how about using an empty method. Means that override parent class and let it empty?

Comment: Same answer.  These questions all come back to whether the behavior of the child class is *sufficiently* like the parent class.

Comment: @StephenC is correct.  If the definition (contract) of the method allows it to be empty, then an empty method will not violate the principle.  The principle is about using a subclass as its base class, so if you pass an instance of the subclass to a method that uses the base class, and the overridden method is called therein, it should behave as the caller expects.

Comment: It is also worth noting that you can violate the Liskov Principle even if you invoke super within an overridden method, if that method then does something unexpected by the base class.

Comment: @Dylon, Thank you very much, so helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

LSP principle is about contracts when you have animal instance or get it from somebody and try to feed it you suppose that dog do what it should do instead of example fly away or trying to kill you. Proper dog implementation that fulfill Animal contract should fit to every place where expects Animal. When dog do something strange (something not in contract) it's violation of LSP. How exactly you implement methods of dog is not matter of context of LSP when they fulfill contracts.

> Substitutability is a principle in object-oriented programming stating that, in a computer program, if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S (i.e. an object of type T may be substituted with any object of a subtype S) without altering any of the desirable properties of T (correctness, task performed, etc.).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: But *feeding* with `no success` (meaning the dog starves despite being fed) is OK (IMHO)...