# liskov substitution principle again - each method overriding violates the principle

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I know there is many similar subjects but I need to ask because the rule is "If class S is a subtype of class T, then instances of T may be replaced by instances of S without altering any of the desirable behaviors of T itself." - so each method overriding violates the rule. Am I wrong?
Because each method overriding alters base class. If not - please give the example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Liskov substitution principle - no overriding/virtual methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735137/liskov-substitution-principle-no-overriding-virtual-methods)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding without calling parent method, violating Liskov Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046418/overriding-without-calling-parent-method-violating-liskov-principle)

Comment: Yes, you are wrong.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56330262/what-does-liskov-substitution-principle-preserve/56335193#56335193

Answer (score 1):

At first, you need to understand concept of abstraction and polymorphism in OOP.

If T is parent class, it should be overridden by child class S given that T is made virtual and S override. 
Example:
T can be BirdClass() with CanFly(), CanEat(), CanSee() methods.
Then S can be Pegion that can override CanFly(), CanEat(), CanSee() methods.
OR Sparrow that can override CanFly(), CanEat(), CanSee() methods of parent class.